# Implementation of interface requires member's redeclaration in a class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, oop, design-patterns

In TypeScript, I have been always doing something like

```
interface People {
    name: string;
}
class Employee implements People {
    name: string;
    foo: string;
}
```

when I implement interfaces through classes.

However, I alway wonder why should I have to redeclare the attributes.

I bought a book about Angular and Design Patterns and read that if you do

```
interface People {
    name: string;
}
class Employee implements People {
    foo: string;
}
```

in TypeScript, that should inherit the properties from the interfaces, so I was surprised.

Then, I have tried but nothing the compiler fails, so is that correct? Should I change something in my tsconfig or whatever like that?

I am curious about this question and I couldn't find a clear answer on GitHub about that, so I would like to not duplicate code or have more boilerplate, if it is possible.

Comment: That second example doesn't work in e.g. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play

Comment: what you are looking for is `extends`, however you can only extend classes with classes, and interfaces with interfaces

Comment: Thx both, that's what I wanted to know...